# Combining tables or not?

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2012, database-schema

I have three tables:

```
TABLENAME: Workers
    Workers_ID
    VNAME
    LNAME
    WindwsUserName
    Sex

TABLENAME: Contract
    Contract_ID
    Hours_to_work
    MA_ID
    Parttime/Fulltime
    Days_of_Holiday
    Days_of_Work_per_week
    Contract_StartDate
```

When does a Worker works. Some ppl work e.g. only Monday 3 hours and Friday 4 hours. So there are thousands of different combinations.

```
TABLENAME: Workdays_Details
    Workdays_Details_ID
    MA_ID
    Monday
    Hours_on_Monday
    Tuesday
    Hours_on_Tuesday
...
```

But after setting up these tables I thought... hmmm... couldnt i put all of this in on table. Since e.g. the `contract_ID` increases with the `MA_ID` in the Contract table cos there are so many individual contracts since everybody could have different `working_per_hours`.

What do you think? Should I put everything into one table or is there a reason why I shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it work for you but maybe you should consider changing the Workdays_Details table to something like MA_ID, Day , Hours and set it as "many to one" relationship with the Contract table and instead of add 2 columns for each day in the table (14 in total), add only 2 in each row.

I think it make a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to use separate tables.